# bash to sh (ash) spoofing

Tags: bash, sh

I have a 3rd party generator that's part of my build process (sbt native packager).  It generates a bash script to be used to run my built program.

Problem is I need to use sh (ash), not bash.  So the generator cranks out a line like this:

```
declare -a app_mainclass=("com.mypackage.Go")
```

sh chokes on this as there is no 'declare' command.

Clever me--I just added these lines:

```
alias declare=''
alias '-a'=''
```

This worked on all such declarations except this one--because of the parens.  sh apparently has no arrays.

Given that I cannot practically change the generator, what can I do to spoof the sh code to behaving properly?  In this case I logically want to eliminate the parens. (If I do this manually in the generated output it works great.)

I was thinking of trying to define a function `app_mainclass= () { app_mainclass=$1; }` but sh didn't like that--complained about the (.  Not sure if there's a way to include the '=' as part of the function name or not.

Any ideas of a way to trick sh into accepting this generated command (the parens)?

Comment: How is `app_mainclass` referenced later?  `${app_mainclass[@]}` is going to be hard to fake.  You'd do best to execute `bash` if the current shell is `sh`.  If you can't rely on `bash` being present, you need to fix the code generator, or use something else to generate the code.

Comment: java -classpath $app_classpath $app_mainclass $@
When its referenced it's used as a single value, not a list or array.  Unfortunately fixing or replacing the generator is not going to be a practical solution.

Comment: OK; you got lucky...sorta...in that case, I'd just post-process the script (`sed`?) and replace that declare with `app_mainclass="com.mypackage.Go"`.  You can't be about to claim that you can't edit the script because you were messing with aliases which would involve tinkering with the script.  But it would be best to fix the generator to generate `sh` code instead of `bash` code.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to suggest it, but you might try a function declaration that uses `eval` to execute any assignments produced by a `declare` statement. I might verify that the generated `declare` statements are "safe" before using this. (For example, that the assigned value doesn't contain any thing that might be executed as arbitrary code by `eval`.)

```
declare () {
    array_decl=
    for arg; do
        # Check if -a is used to declare an array
        [ "$arg" = -a ] && array_decl=1
        # Ignore non-assignment arguments
        expr "$arg" : '.*=.*' || continue
        # Split the assignment into separate name and value
        IFS='=' read -r name value <<EOF
$arg
EOF
        # If it's an array assignment, strip the leading and trailing parentheses
        if [ -n "array_decl" ]; then
            value=${value#(}
            value=${value%)}
        fi
        # Cross your fingers... I'm assuming `$value` was already quoted, as in your example.
        eval "$name=$value"
    done
}
```