# translation from bash to ash shell: how to handle arrays defined by input?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, alpine-linux

I try to transfer the excellent example [docker-haproxy](https://github.com/paulczar/docker-haproxy) from centos to alpine.

A shell script is used to process a list of values given as parameters to the script into an array, then write these values plus their index to some file.

The following construction works in bash:

```
ServerArray=${SERVERS:=$1}
...
for i in ${ServerArray[@]}
do
  echo "   " server SERVER_$COUNT $i >> /haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  let "COUNT += 1"
done
```

but not in ash (or sh):

```
syntax error: bad substitution
```

The error refers to line

```
for i in ${ServerArray[@]}
```

What is the correct syntax here? I guess the line

```
ServerArray=${SERVERS:=$1}
```

does not define an array as intended, but googling for long did not help me.

[bash to sh (ash) spoofing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065071/bash-to-sh-ash-spoofing) says

> sh apparently has no arrays.

If so, how to solve the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can do with this construction:

```
#!/bin/sh
# test.sh
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

delivers

```
/ #  ./test 172.17.0.2:3306 172.17.0.3:3306
172.17.0.2:3306
172.17.0.3:3306
```

which is what I need to proceed